# USRP X300 FPGA images compatibility

Tags: ubuntu, fpga, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp

I am tying to connect a USRP X300 to my laptop. I did install all packages needed.

When I ran `uhd_find_devices`, it worked fine.

But the `uhd_usrp_probe` gives a problem in FPGA compatibility as follows:

```
uhd_usrp_probe --args addr=192.168.10.2
{
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 9.4.0; Boost_107100; UHD_4.2.0.1-0ubuntu1~focal1

[INFO] [X300] X300 initialization sequence...

Error: RuntimeError: Expected FPGA compatibility number 38, but got 13:

The FPGA image on your device is not compatible with this host code build.

Download the appropriate FPGA images for this version of UHD.

Please run:

 "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/uhd/utils/uhd_images_downloader.py"

Then burn a new image to the on-board flash storage of your
USRP X3xx device using the image loader utility. Use this command:

"/lib/bin/uhd_image_loader" --args="type=x300,addr=192.168.10.2"

For more information, refer to the UHD manual:

 http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_usrp_x3x0.html#x3x0_flash}
```

I updated the FPGA images and rebuilt `gnuradio`, but nothing has changed.

I also followed the commands listed above, but it still gives the error.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: you're probably using different versions of UHD on your system. Uninstall *all* UHD you have and only install exactly one version.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have one issue when I use the same usrp with gnuradio. When I created and ran a simple flowgraph, the same error (FPGA images are not compatible) appeared on gnuradio command line. The issue is that the UHD version of usrp is 4.2.0.1 while the gnuradio uhd is 3.15.  So, I re-installed the gnuradio to get the latest uhd version, but that still gives uhd 3.15. to install GNU Radio using the already-installed UHD 4.2.0.1.??

Comment: like with any other software, it needs to use the libraries in the versions it was built against.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the X300 FPGA image is not compatible with the UHD version. Compatibility number 38 is required by UHD4, while the image on the X300 is rather old (compatibility number 13). The FPGA image can be updated by running the command
`"/lib/bin/uhd_image_loader" --args="type=x300,addr=192.168.10.2"`.
You shouldn't need to run `uhd_images_downloader.py` or rebuild GNURadio. Remember to power cycle the X300 after updating the firmware.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I already solved the problem. There were two uhd versions (4.2.0.1 and 4.1), so I deleted the old version and kept the latest one.